# Possible to get EMR bootstrap script location from within script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

The use case is I've got a bootstrap script at s3://path/to/something/bootstrap.sh and I'd like to (within that bootstrap) download other files located at s3://path/to/something.

The only thought at the moment is passing the script location as an argument, but that's non-ideal as it changes the invocation of the script, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Can you add "aws s3 cp s3://path/to/something /home/hadoop/" command in your BA script that does the job?

Comment: @annunarcist need to avoid that as `/path/to/something` needs to be configurable independently (i.e. can't be hardcoded in the BA script). (There's a separate script that will upload the bootstrap, as well as other useful things to a configurable location. Then, the bootstrap needs to access those other useful things.)